# Dynamically update a Javafx node based on GPS input

Tags: javafx-11

I have developed a Javafx chat application for use with radios. The radios provide gps locations which I plot onto a map.
The GPS update and Map methods all work eg I can plot correctly on the Map however I am not sure how to approach removing old GPS locations and only show current locations as users move. There may be only 3 name variables (eg radios) however the lat and long values change for the name as they move. Any suggestions regards approach welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
public void addRadios(String name, double latval, double longitudeval) {
    this.name = name;
    this.latval = latval;
    this.longitudeval = longitudeval;

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!radionames.contains(name)) {
                radionames.add(name);
                MercatorMap mapinfo = new MercatorMap(900, 700);
                xpoint = mapinfo.getScreenX((float) longitudeval);
                ypoint = mapinfo.getScreenY((float) latval);
                Circle radio = new Circle();
                radio.setLayoutX(xpoint);
                radio.setLayoutY(ypoint);
                radio.setRadius(5);
                radio.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                pane.getChildren().add(radio);
                radioCircles.add(radio);

            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: store the values in javafx properties and either bind your components to it, or add a listener to them, which updates the map

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using binding. For some reason I could not see the trees for the forest. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a simple approach which worked for my requirement as follows:

```
    public void addRadios(String name, double latval, double longitudeval) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latval = latval;
        this.longitudeval = longitudeval;
        if (!radionames.contains(name)) {
            radionames.add(name);
        }

        if (name != null) {
            updatePli(name, latval, longitudeval);
        }

    }

    public void updatePli(String name, double latitude, double longditude) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MercatorMap mapinfo = new MercatorMap(900, 700);
                boolean old = false;
                for (Circle radio : radioCircles) {
                    if (radio.getId().equals(name)) {
                        xpoint = mapinfo.getScreenX((float) longditude);
                        ypoint = mapinfo.getScreenY((float) latitude);
                        radio.setLayoutX(xpoint);
                        radio.setLayoutY(ypoint);
                        old = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!old) {
                    xpoint = mapinfo.getScreenX((float) longditude);
                    ypoint = mapinfo.getScreenY((float) latitude);
                    radio = new Circle();
                    radio.setLayoutX(xpoint);
                    radio.setLayoutY(ypoint);
                    radio.setId(name);
                    radio.setRadius(5);
                    radio.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    pane.getChildren().addAll(radio);
                    radioCircles.add(radio);
                }
            }

        });
    }
    
}
```